# Decoding JSON dictionaries in Swift - "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead"

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, parsing, decode

I'm new to Swift and programming. I am having some trouble decoding a JSON file.

I have JSON that looks like:

```
{
    "actors": {
        "2048": "Gary Busey", 
        "3": "Harrison Ford", 
        "5251": "Jack Warden", 
        "14343": "Rene Russo", 
        "51214": "Brad Renfro", 
        "9560": "Ellen Burstyn"
    }
}
```

My model is:

```
struct Actors: Codable {
    let actors: [String: String]
}
```

I'm using [this extension](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-decode-json-from-your-app-bundle-the-easy-way) from hackingwithswift.com to decode the JSON.

When I call:

```
let actors = Bundle.main.decode([String: String].self, from: "actors.json")
```

I get this error:

"Failed to decode actors.json from bundle due to type mismatch – Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead."

I feel like I am missing something simple. Any ideas on what I am missing here?

Comment: Why you don't use your struct `Actors`? It should be `Actors.self`, or if you don't want to use you struct, `[String: [String: String]].self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decoding with `let actors = Bundle.main.decode([String: String].self, from: "actors.json")` would work if you had a JSON like this:

```
{
    "2048": "Gary Busey", 
    "3": "Harrison Ford", 
    "5251": "Jack Warden", 
    "14343": "Rene Russo", 
    "51214": "Brad Renfro", 
    "9560": "Ellen Burstyn"
}
```

But you have additionally a dictionary with a string key and a dictionary value. Try this:

```
let actors = Bundle.main.decode([[String: [String: String]].self, from: "actors.json")
```

Or this:

```
let actors = Bundle.main.decode(Actors.self, from: "actors.json")
```

Comment: If anyone else comes across this,

`let actors = Bundle.main.decode([[String: [String: String]].self, from: "actors.json")`

should be 

`let actors = Bundle.main.decode([String: [String: String]].self, from: "actors.json")`

Comment: No, you should use `Actor.self`. You already have the type.